# Complex roots of 1

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z$ be $n$ power root of 1

Calculate
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2z^{k-1}$$
as $z=1$ and also when $z\neq 1$

I could use some help on this problem.

Comment: Hint: if $z$ is an $n^\text{th}$ root of $1$ then $z^{k-1}$ takes only finitely many values as $k$ ranges over the positive integers.

Comment: @Antonio I don't see how that helps, since the range $1\le k\le n$ allows each $n$th root exactly once (if $z$ is primitive, say). Using a general formula for $\sum k^2 z^k$ and *then* using the fact that $z\in\mu_n$ is the way to go here, no?

Comment: @seaturtles, sure, that would work too.

Comment: @Antonio Well, I don't understand what your method is.

Comment: @seaturtles, for example, suppose $n$ is even and $z = -1$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 z^{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} (2k-1)^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} (2k)^2$.  Expand and simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  See if you can fill in the gaps.  Summing a geometric series involving a variable $z$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n z^k=???$$
Differentiating,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n kz^{k-1}=???$$
Multiplying by $z$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n kz^k=???$$
Differentiating again,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2z^{k-1}=???$$
Using $z=1$ (for your first question) or $z^n=1$ (for your second question), simplify the answer.

Good luck!